# How to use OR condition with COUNTIFS?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I want to count all the cells in the column where the date is either after 30th April[&`DATE(2018,4,30)`] or it is blank[`""`].

```
=Countifs($N$2:$N$24388,{">"&DATE(2018,4,30),""})
```

Going by the syntax, I feel I am doing it right since it's not throwing any error either but it's not giving the correct result.

Later I find out that it's rendering only up till the first condition i.e. the above formula is rendering like this:

```
=Countifs($N$2:$N$24388,{">"&DATE(2018,4,30)})
```

It's not accounting for the condition meant for blank("") cells. So the result is incorrect or lesser than what it's supposed to be.

Later I changed the order of condition i.e. to this

```
=Countifs($N$2:$N$24388,{"",">"&DATE(2018,4,30)})
```

Now, it is acknowledging the only (`""`) condition and ignoring the latter one. So, it's giving the same result as what the below formula would give.

```
=Countifs($N$2:$N$24388,{">"&DATE(2018,4,30)})
```

Eventually, I tried the following and it worked but it's a lengthy formula and defeats the purpose of having `Countifs`

```
=sum(COUNTIFS(N2:N24388,{""})+COUNTIFS($N$2:$N$24388,{">"&DATE(2018,4,30)}))
```

As I stated, I expect to get the count of all the cells which are either blank OR satisfy a given condition.

Comment: from the [Office Support page](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842), it looks like the order is Countifs(**range1, criteria1**, **range2, criteria2**).

Did you try `Countifs($N$2:$N$24388,{">"&DATE(2018,4,30)}, $N$2:$N$24388,"")` ?

Answer (score 2):

Just add two separate `COUNTIF`s together:

```
=COUNTIF($N$2:$N$24388,">"&DATE(2018,4,30))+COUNTIF($N$2:$N$24388,"")
```

This doesn't defeat the purpose of `COUNTIFS` as you suggest, since `COUNTIFS` counts values which satisfy all the criteria you specify, whereas you're interested in values which satisfy at least one criterion.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **`COUNTBLANK`**:

```
=COUNTIF($N$2:$N$24388, ">"&DATE(2018, 4, 30))+
 COUNTBLANK($N$2:$N$24388)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your COUNTIFS returns an array of results, so just sum them:

```
=SUM(Countifs($N$2:$N$24388,{">"&DATE(2018,4,30),""}))
```